# get name of variables from user in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, var, let

I have an object that name is "car":

```
function car(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.position= 0;
}
```

i get the number of cars from user:

```
let nubmerOfCars = +prompt("Input Number of Casr")
```

and create cars to the number entered with name that user entered for each one the end, push cars to array:

```
for (i = 0; i < nubmerOfCars; i++) { 
    let nameCar = prompt("Input name of car no." + `${i+1}` + ":");
    let temp = new car(nameCar);
    temp.name = nameCar;
    nameCar=temp;
    carsArray.push(nameCar);
    carsArray.push(temp);
}
// user entered a,b,c for cars name
carsArray=[car{name:a},car{name:b},car{name:c}] // for 3 cars
```

but, i want for each car, create a variable with user entered name, such it:

```
function car() { //remove names's key
        this.position= po;
    }
//user entered a,b,c for cars name
    let a = new car{...};
    let b = new car{...};
    let c = new car{...};
```

really i want create variables that the user has entered names
can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create variable names that way, workaround could be to create an object:

```js
let carsArray=[{name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"}]

let carObj = {};

carsArray.forEach((car) => {
  carObj[car.name]=car
});

console.log(carObj)
```

Comment: Can you please be precise about what you are not getting understood?

Comment: please see it: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp and see this section "Object Types (Blueprints) (Classes)". the only way to assign variable to object is manual? ("myFather" and "myMother" variable assign to obj manually?

Comment: There are other ways as well:

https://dzone.com/articles/easy-javascript-part-13-four-ways-to-create-object

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to add variables named by javascript itself to the local scope. But usually the global scope exists as an object instance, and this is changeable. Like `window` on client site JS:

```js
// set variable x using the window object
window.x = "This is the value of x";
// accessing window.x only writing x
alert(x); // will alert: This is the value of x

// use string to define a variable name
window["y"] = "test";
// accessing...
alert(y); // will alert: test

// using other variable to define variable name
window[y] = 123;
// accessing...
alert(test): // will alert: 123
```